# C# Fluent-validations

Tags: c#, fluentvalidation

I have the following fluent validation, is working partially. If I enter the 3 requested values is working, but if I enter 2 values is working too. It's supposed to do not works because all the 3 values are mandatory.

```
 RuleFor(x => x.Entities).Must(list => list.Count == 3)
            .WithMessage("The Entities list must contain 3 items and for AmendmentParties the RelationType must be CurrentName, ChangeAddName and AuthorizingPartyName ");
        RuleForEach(x => x.Entities).ChildRules(x =>
        {
            x.RuleFor(x => x.RelationType).Equals(EntityAmendmentRelation.CurrentName)
            .Equals(EntityAmendmentRelation.ChangeAddName)
            .Equals(EntityAmendmentRelation.AuthorizingPartyName);
        });
```

The request is the following: The goals are that the entities list must contain 3 items, and in each item, the RelationType properties need to be different.

```
 "entities": [
        {
            "ObjectType": "SecuredParty",
            "reqSearchID": "NoSearch",
            "RelationType": "CurrentName",
            "altCapacity": "NoAltCapacity",
            "OrganizationName": "Secured Party",
            "Address": {
                "StreetAddress": "12345 Main Street",
                "City": "Sacramento",
                "State": "CA",
                "PostalCode": "95811",
                "Country": "USA"
            }
        },
        {
            "ObjectType": "SecuredParty",
            "reqSearchID": "NoSearch",
            "RelationType": "ChangeAddName",
            "altCapacity": "NoAltCapacity",
            "OrganizationName": "Secured Party",
            "Address": {
                "StreetAddress": "12345 Main Street",
                "City": "Sacramento",
                "State": "CA",
                "PostalCode": "95811",
                "Country": "USA"
            }
        },
        {
            "ObjectType": "SecuredParty",
            "reqSearchID": "NoSearch",
            "RelationType": "AuthorizingPartyName",
            "altCapacity": "NoAltCapacity",
            "OrganizationName": "Secured Party",
            "Address": {
                "StreetAddress": "12345 Main Street",
                "City": "Sacramento",
                "State": "CA",
                "PostalCode": "95811",
                "Country": "USA"
            }
    }
```

Comment: Write a function to check items and call it on Must clause

Comment: What do you mean by working? It doesn't throw an exception but return result. If you need it to throw an exception use `validator.ValidateAndThrow`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what you expect from validator to do.

By default if you write

```
var results = validator.Validate(new TestData
{
    Entities = new List<string> { "", "" }
});
```

It doesn't throw an exception but return result which you can check later.

```
bool success = results.IsValid;
```

If you need it to throw an exception use it the following way:

```
validator.ValidateAndThrow(new TestData
{
    Entities = new List<string> { "", "" }
});
```

So, for me the validation for the both methods works for the following configuration

```
public class TestDataValidator : AbstractValidator<TestData>
{
    public TestDataValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.Entities).Must(list => list.Count == 3)
        .WithMessage("The Entities list must contain 3 items and for AmendmentParties the RelationType must be CurrentName, ChangeAddName and AuthorizingPartyName ");
    }

}
```

Using first approach `result.IsValid` is false; using `ValidateAndThrow` throws an exception.